# Error encountered bailing. network state unknown. TypeError: contract.detectNetwork is no a fnction

Tags: truffle-migration, erc-721

I used "Zeppelin-solidity" to publish the ERC 721 token and compiled the sample code with truffle. However When migrating with "truffle", the following error occurs. Why?

> > Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
> >     TypeError: contract.detectNetwork is not a function 
> >     　　at C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\truffle-deployer\src\actions\deploy.js:6:1 
> >     　　at C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\truffle-deployer\src\deferredchain.js:20:1
> >     　　at

I am using truffle v4.1.7 solidity v0.4.23

Thanking you in advance

Comment: Was self resolved::　migrate　「deployer.deploy(MyToken, name,symbol);」was correct though it was 「deployer.deploy(name,symbol);」

Comment: There is not enough details to diagnose this issue. But also this was pre-release software (ERC-721 wasn't even finalized at that time and Zeppelin code was pretty terrible at that time). Voting to close.